# Fixed column in table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I need your help to fix the first column in responsive screen
This is my table :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Hover Rows</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Number</th>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Username</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Number 1</td>
                                <td>Mark</td>
                                <td>Otto</td>
                                <td>@mdo</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Number 2</td>
                                <td>Jacob</td>
                                <td>Thornton</td>
                                <td>@fat</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Number 3</td>
                                <td>Larry</td>
                                <td>the Bird</td>
                                <td>@twitter</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/faissal_aboullait/5g523nqx/
What i need is that the first column (Number) still fixed in responsive design, I tried out a lot of solutions in stackoverflow but nothing work for my case.

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by "fixed" in this context?

Comment: Like this example. in responsive screen : http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/FixedColumns/examples/bootstrap.html.

Comment: Its not fixed, its your perception. Resize your screen and move it from left to right , then you will find the difference.

Comment: Yes it's not fixed and this is the probleme i need to change it to be fixed

Comment: I need help, Nobody here ?

Answer (score 0):

try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zS7Ny/

```
.wrap {
    width: 352px;
}

.wrap table {
    width: 300px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table tr td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

table.head tr td {
    background: #eee;
}

.inner_table {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

<div class="wrap">
    <table class="head">
        <tr>
            <td>Head 1</td>
            <td>Head 1</td>
            <td>Head 1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="inner_table">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
            <td>Body 1</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Some more tr's -->
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not useful anymore. I said the first column not the first row

Comment: And i can't use two tables. I must use just one

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this:

```
tr td:nth-child(1){
    width: 100px;
}
```

It will force every first cell to be with a fixed size

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5g523nqx/1/)